# Apache Cordova and Jquery-Ajax Requests

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cordova

I just try with Apache Cordova and normal jQuery to make an Ajax-Request.
I have this code so far:

```
    function onDeviceReady() {
    // Handle the Cordova pause and resume events
    document.addEventListener( 'pause', onPause.bind( this ), false );
    document.addEventListener( 'resume', onResume.bind( this ), false );

    // TODO: Cordova has been loaded. Perform any initialization that requires Cordova here.
    $(function () {
        var datastring = "test";
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "serverfiles/app-db-connection.php",
            data: dataString,
            success: function (data) {
                $('#result').html(data);
                alert("test");
            }
        });
        $('#result').html("test");

    });
};
```

the .php file is local and works, if I call it through the browser. Also the ajax-Part works fine in other normal webprojects.

So, what should I care about, then useing cordova. There have to be some issues with cordova.
Even the test-alert isn't working.

A little hints how normal Ajax-requests work with cordova would help me a lot.

Normal Jquery-Code is working fine on the test-machines.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. just solve the problem. 
2 mistakes done:
first: Var datastring and "dataString" were not written equal.
second: it is not allowed to use in url-property a relative file-path. This because the file will not compiled by the app it self... it has to be an absolute path: http://blabla.com ... not ir works fine.